# Failed to bootstrap model, cannot start Juju bootstrap instance

Tags: server, virtualbox, juju, maas, openstack

I am currently following the guide from [Openstack.org](https://docs.openstack.org/project-deploy-guide/charm-deployment-guide/latest/install-juju.html)
and have deployed the MAAS (192.168.100.1) and Juju on 2 virtual machines (in VirtualBox).

However, at the below step, I get the following error and I'm not sure where the problem is:

```
juju bootstrap --constraints tags=juju mymaas maas-controller
```

Error:

```
Creating Juju controller "maas-controller" on mymaas
Looking for packaged Juju agent version 2.3.8 for amd64
No packaged binary found, preparing local Juju agent binary
Launching controller instance(s) on mymaas... 
ERROR failed to bootstrap model: cannot start bootstrap instance: failed to acquire node: unexpected : ServerError: 400 Bad Request ({"tags": ["No such tags(s): 'juju'."]})
```

Note:

1. I have tried this using 16.04 and 18.04 and same problem
2. The Juju Server VM, has 2 interfaces ; 1 is configured to NAT to access the internet, and the other is configured to "Internal Network"(192.168.100.0/24)

Comment: Log in to your MAAS and see if you have any nodes that are tagged as juju. To me error says - "I can not find any free nodes available with tag juju where i can provision new vm"   I have used following command in my deployment       juju bootstrap myMAAS myMAAS-controller

Comment: There is nothing in the MAAS portal.. However  this is what happens when I change the command.

Comment: Did you try     " juju bootstrap  mymaas maas-controller"

Comment: #sudo juju bootstrap --constraints "mem=2G" mymaas maas-controller  Creating Juju controller "maas-controller" on mymaas
Looking for packaged Juju agent version 2.3.8 for amd64
No packaged binary found, preparing local Juju agent binary
Launching controller instance(s) on mymaas...
ERROR failed to bootstrap model: cannot start bootstrap instance in availability zone "default": failed to acquire node: No available machine matches constraints: [('agent_name', ['b709895b-c03b-4f1d-8047-a912561f935c']), ('mem', ['2048']), ('zone', ['default'])] (resolved to "mem=2048.0 zone=default")

Comment: ok "create" the machine with required specs and add it to MAAS. Do you use KVM or physical hardware?

Comment: If time permits i will test instructions from your link in my lab.

Comment: All in virtual Machine. I want to test the commands so that before I deploy in my Data center I know what I am doing. Thank you very much.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78236/discussion-between-bogdan-and-charm-quark).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have covered quite a lot over the chat but i think the crucial piece of info thats missing in instruction is/was to add hardware or VM resources to MAAS. Error comes up when JUJU request resources from MAAS and MAAS is not able to provide it as it doesn't have any hardware associated. There are couple of options that you can use here. 1 create VMs via virsh or uvt-tool or add your physical hardware as nodes.

Comment: I tried to replicate this behavior in my lab and was unsuccessful. I came back to this post and noticed that you are using VirtualBox.  I dont think that this will work with VB. Ideally you would want to use KVM, provision machines and later add them as resources (either as nodes or pod to MAAS). During our chat i have also sent you a snippet of what settings i am using to create my VMs. For Openstack you will want to create all those separate disks just as per our chat. Let me know if you need any more help. Thanks.